# Getting Atom to execute shell scripts in Ubuntu, not Windows PowerShell

Tags: atom-editor, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Atom in Windows 10 to edit shell scripts, but right now when I hit "shift-control-B" to execute them from Atom via Atom's "script" package, they use Windows PowerShell, and I'd rather they use Ubuntu (via the Windows Subsystem for Linux), which is what I normally use for shell scripting outside Atom. How can I get Atom to use the Ubuntu shell as the default?